# Excel formula index match

Tags: vba, excel-formula, formula

I've got a column `U` and a column `L`.
What I need to get is the value from column L when searched in column U.

```
    Column L          Column U  
      516               11  
      123               11   
      74                5  
      46                11
      748               21  
      156               11  
      189               21
```

For example:
I want to search 21 in column U but need to find the last one. 
So if I want the value belonging to 21 I need to get 189.

I tried it with:
       `=INDEX($L$10:$L$500,MACTH(D2,$U$10:$U$500,0))`
But this gets me the first 21 value so 748 as answer.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE Instead of MATCH:

```
=INDEX($L:$L,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($U$10:$U$500)/($U$10:$U$500=D2),1))
```

The AGGREGATE will return the highest row number to the INDEX where the `($U$10:$U$500=D2)` resolves to TRUE.

[image]

Comment: It works, atleast kinda. If I try 5, I get the results of the 11 below. It looks like it gets the highest value of the next number and not the value of my input

Comment: Did you put my formula as is?  notice that I am using a full column reference `$L:$L` in the INDEX and not `$L$10:$L$500`

Comment: @EfhK See edit for proof that it works using your data.

Comment: You are fantastic! I indeed did change the $L:$L, thanks for the help!

Comment: If you got it working please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Something is going wrong.. I've got 15, 15, 25, 25 it get's the latest 25 while it must get the first.. So to better format my question maybe that when the value changes I need to get the value..

Comment: You stated in your question `but need to find the last one` so that is what this does, it finds the last one in the list.  Not sure what you are now asking.  You may want to ask a new question and better explain your needs.

Comment: I changed the question, maybe it's now a bit more clear. I am sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Please do not change the question after getting answers it opens us up to down votes.  And with an accepted answer very few if none will come to see your edit.  Please ask a new question.  Revert this one to the old question and post a new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138845/discussion-between-efhk-and-scott-craner).

Comment: @EfhK this is not VBA, try to label better your questions